# Cannot use UI router, shows error for ui-view , ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I cannot use UI router, I injected it. but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code's screenshot.

[image: Please see the screenshot here]

Comment: The line you have in your edior doesn't mean you can not use it.
Have you tried to run your code?

Answer (score 1):

you have that row because your editor doesn't know the attribute `ui-view`.

It doesn't mean your can not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed any `template` to `ui.router`, so its not working. Line underneath showing that it has no value, asking your motive to write `ui-view`? Inject a `template` and it will be gone. and if you need further assistance let me know, else accept my answer so that this thread can be closed.

Comment: i did that , i defined template and state url everything, it doesn't work

Comment: @Amaan Imtiyaz can you share your code with me, or made a snippet so that i can see, what you are doing wrong?